# Spring AuthenticationManager.authenticate not called

Tags: spring, spring-security

We have the following Spring Security Config with our Spring Boot 3.1.1 application:
The dependency added:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authz -> authz
                                .anyRequest().authenticated());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        return createDummyAuthenticationManager();
    }

    private AuthenticationManager createDummyAuthenticationManager() {
        return new AuthenticationManager() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                return new Authentication() {
                    @Override public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                        return List.of();
                    }

                    @Override public Object getCredentials() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override public Object getDetails() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override public Object getPrincipal() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override public boolean isAuthenticated() {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {

                    }

                    @Override public String getName() {
                        return "test";
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }

}
```

We would expect the `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` function to be called on any incoming request. But it's never called. We get a 403 straight away.
Are we missing something?

Comment: Why would it need to be called? It will only be called on authentication request, as you haven't configured any mechanism for this what is it that should call it? If you would add `httpBasic()` and pass and `Authentication` header it would be called.